# Merging dataframes in pandas - Keep getting key error?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two data frames, testr and testc, but I keep getting a Key Error on "Channel ID" and not sure what the problem is. Do the dataframes have to be the same size or have the same datatype for pd.merge to work? Here is my code to merge with .info() on each dataframe:

```
def matchID_RC(rev,cost):
    rc = pd.merge(rev, cost, on='Channel ID', how = 'outer')
    return rc

testr.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 169 entries, 0 to 168
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Channel ID         169 non-null int64
Channel Name       169 non-null object
Impressions        169 non-null object
Fill Rate          169 non-null object
Gross Rev          169 non-null object
Impression Fees    169 non-null object
Exchange Fees      169 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 10.6+ KB

testc.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 63 entries, 0 to 62
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Channel ID    62 non-null object
Campaign      63 non-null object
Ad Spend      63 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.0+ KB
```

Answer (score 0):

They need to be the same data type. After all, you can't compare whether a string and an integer are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `'Channel ID'` does exist in the two dataframes, however, in one it is defined as `object` and in the other as `int`.

This can be fixed with `convert_objects`:

```
def matchID_RC(rev,cost,col='Channel ID'):
    rev[col]=rev[col].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    cost[col]=cost[col].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    rc = pd.merge(rev, cost, on=col, how = 'outer')
    return rc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change from "on" to "left_on" and "right_on" for better parsings as stated in the official document from Pandas:

> Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both
> DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes then this
> defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

[image]